# Why can't i set the Guid in those components? / What have i to do to reach my goal?

Tags: xml, wix, installation, guid

so i need to modify an per-machine installer into an per-user installer (LocalAppDataPath).

Right now I have some bad troubles with my Component Guis. My Code is like this:

```
<Component Guid="">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\CompanyName\$(var.Name)">
      <RegistryValue Name="$(var.Name).exe" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" Type="integer" />
    </RegistryKey>

    <File Source="$(var.SolutionDir)ControlBoard\bin\$(var.Configuration)\File1.dll" />       
  </Component>

  <Component Guid="">    
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\CompanyName\$(var.Name)">
      <RegistryValue Name="$(var.Name).exe" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" Type="integer" />
    </RegistryKey>

    <File Source="$(var.SolutionDir)ControlBoard\bin\$(var.Configuration)\File2.dll" />
  </Component>
```

Error is: Duplicate Symbol 'Component:reg734DBF...' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated.
I understand this error but what am I supposed to do now? Setting the Guid to '*' doesn't work either.

This could be a silly question because i have like Zero Knowledge with this.

Thank you for every Reply!

Comment: It could be that you need to have unique Ids on your Components

Comment: as the other commenter said you should add `Id="RegistryIDHere"`to your two registry key elements. Since you don't have an Id, wix tries to auto generate one for the MSI database using the key and registry value name. Since they are the same it generates identical names. You probably shouldn't be using registry keys for all your Keypaths of components. use `KeyPath="yes"` on the file and remove the registry key entries.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic guid generation is based on paths, the registry location in this case, and both of those components have the same root. So you get duplicate guids.

Why are there two identical keypath components? That's the root cause of the problem. What problem are you trying to solve there?